# Quick way of checking what SQL Server host has significant latency issues?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, aws-aurora-serverless

We're in the process of publishing our mobile app to the Apple and Google stores, but I'm somewhat concerned about latency and speed issues.

I've always paid for the same shared host (which I never actually use), but I recently purchased three other shared SQL Server hosts.

All three have the same DB objects, and I want execute a stored procedure that returns all 90 rows from a table.

Locally, I'll connect to the hosts via SSMS, run the SP and compare the latency results. The one with the lowest latency will host our app database.

Is there something that straightforward? It doesn't have to be an exact science; it's just something to easily measure speeds.

My goal is that, whatever issues may arise from the app, I can be certain that the database backend is not one of them.

Comment: The lowest latency to YOU doesn't mean it's the lowest latency to your users.

Comment: But we're all on the same island, and the shared hosts are in Miami, NY, Virginia,  or "US 
East".

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!